# Asp.net core form always returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm trying to build one view that includes all (Create, Edit, Delete, and Index) in one View which is Index.

**The problem is with Editing. Always returns null to the controller as shown in the gif.**

[image]

I have Model and ViewModel as follows.

**The Model BootstrapCategory**

```
public class BootstrapCategory
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    [Required]
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

**The ViewModel VMBPCategoris**

```
public class VMBPCategoris
{
    public List<BootstrapCategory> bootstrapCategories { get; set; }
    public BootstrapCategory bootstrapCategory { get; set; }
}
```

**The View**

> Note: Edit not by the usual button in the table it instead by another
> button as shown in the gif

```
@model VMBPCategoris

        @foreach (var item in Model.bootstrapCategories)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
                        <div class="@item.Id d-none">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input id="btnGroupEdit" type="submit" value="Save" class="input-group-text btn btn-primary" />
                                <input asp-for="@item.Category" class="form-control" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupEdit">
                            </div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="@item.Category" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <div class="@item.Id">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
                    </div>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@item.Id" class="ToggleEdit">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

**The Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([Bind("Id,Category")] BootstrapCategory bootstrapCategory)
{

    _context.Update(bootstrapCategory);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    //return View(vMBPCategoris);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The view model class VMBPCategoris needs to have its members properties assigned to instances in a constructor:

```
public class VMBPCategoris
{
    public List<BootstrapCategory> bootstrapCategories { get; set; }
    public BootstrapCategory bootstrapCategory { get; set; }

    public VMBPCategoris()
    {
        bootstrapCategories = new List<BootstrapCategory>();
        bootstrapCategory = new BootstrapCategory();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a name to your input tag.Change your form like below.

```
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" name="Id"/>
            <div class="@item.Id d-none">
                <div class="input-group">
                     <input id="btnGroupEdit" type="submit" value="Save" class="input-group-text btn btn-primary" />
                     <input asp-for="@item.Category" name="Category" class="form-control" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupEdit">
                </div>
                     <span asp-validation-for="@item.Category" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an easy solution by changing a little bit with the ViewModel and using the value attribute to get value from a model and using asp-for to set a value to another model.

It's all clarified in that [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000406/how-to-use-asp-for-to-get-value-from-a-model-and-set-value-to-another-model/68001516#68001516)