# How to use asp-for to get value from a model and set value to another model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm trying to build one view that includes all (Create, Edit, Delete, and Index) in one View which is Index.

**The problem is with Editing. Always returns null to the controller as shown in the gif.**

> I know what is the problem but I can't solve it. *The explanation at the end of the question after the hr line*

[image]

I have Model and ViewModel as follows.

**The Model BootstrapCategory**

```
public class BootstrapCategory
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    [Required]
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

**The ViewModel VMBPCategoris**

```
public class VMBPCategoris
{
    public List<BootstrapCategory> bootstrapCategories { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

**The View**

> Note: Edit not by the usual button in the table it instead by another
> button as shown in the gif

```
@model VMBPCategoris

        @foreach (var item in Model.bootstrapCategories)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
                        <div class="@item.Id d-none">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input id="btnGroupEdit" type="submit" value="Save" class="input-group-text btn btn-primary" />
                                <input asp-for="@item.Category" class="form-control" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupEdit">
                            </div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="@item.Category" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <div class="@item.Id">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
                    </div>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@item.Id" class="ToggleEdit">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

**The Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([Bind("Id,Category")] BootstrapCategory bootstrapCategory)
{

    _context.Update(bootstrapCategory);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    //return View(vMBPCategoris);
}
```

---

**In the ViewModel VMBPCategoris**

The problem, I get the list of Category values from this list

```
 public List<BootstrapCategory>bootstrapCategories { get; set; }
```

on edit, I set a new value to one member in the list, not to this

```
 public Guid Id { get; set; }
 public string Category { get; set; }
```

So that It returns Null

> However, if I change **asp-for="@item.Category"**  to
> **asp-for="Category"** the input gets empty value, but it returns the edited value not empty

**Here is my question >> can I use asp-for to get value from

```
  public List<BootstrapCategory> bootstrapCategories { get; set; }
```

**and set value to**

```
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Category { get; set; }
```

Because,
using **asp-for="@item.Category"** is beneficial to get category values but not for setting a value.
And using **asp-for="Category"** is beneficial to set category value but not for getting a value.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a very simple solution.

to get values I used

```
value="@item.Category"
```

and to set a value I used

```
asp-for="Category"
```

That's it ...

```
<input asp-for="Category" value="@item.Category" class="form-control">
```

**In that way, I can get a value from a model and set a value to another model**